# Custom styled arrows Tooltipster

Tags: css, tooltipster

I'm using tooltipster with custom styling. But I need the arrow to be bigger (30px in stead of default 7/8px). But when I create the custom css the arrows look great, but the position of the tooltip is wrong and overlaps the hotspot. (still based on the original 'small' arrow).

[image: snippet]

I styled the arrows by overriding the .tooltipster-arrow-left/right span with:

```
 .tooltipster-arrow-left span {
    border-top: 30px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 30px solid;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    right: -30px;
}

.tooltipster-arrow-right span {
    border-top: 30px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 30px solid;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
}
```

Is there a way to tell tooltipster what the size of the arrow will be?
Or can I set an offset?

I tried adding a margin to the .tooltipster-base, but this doesn't work well. It only works for either left positioned tooltip or right positioned tooltip and not for both.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tooltipster v4 (experimental) on the v4 branch of the project and you will be able to change the size of the arrow. Some of the packaged themes change the size of the arrow of the default style, see how it's done there.

Answer (score 0):

I used this css style for my themed tooltipster to increase arrow size for top and bottom align

```
.tooltipster-arrow-top span, .tooltipster-arrow-top-right span, .tooltipster-arrow-top-left span {
    border-left: 12px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent !important;
    border-top: 12px solid;
    bottom: -12px;
}

.tooltipster-arrow-bottom span, .tooltipster-arrow-bottom-right span, .tooltipster-arrow-bottom-left span {
    border-bottom: 12px solid;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent !important;
    top: -12px;
}
```